# Harvesting equation bifurcation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to make a bifurcation diagram of a two parameter ODE of a harvesting model.

It's 
$$
\dot{x} = ax\left(1 - \frac{x}{b}\right)- \frac{x^2}{1 + x^2}.
$$

If I set the two parts equal, $a\left(1 - \frac{x}{b}\right) = \frac{x}{1 + x^2}$ I see that I can get three, two, or one equilibrium points depending on the slope of the line by changing $a$ and $b$ , yet I'm stumped on how to diagram such a thing to find bifurcation points.

I'm not looking for a solution as much as source or tip to get started on two parameter problems.

Comment: So, you have a regions on parameter plane where you can have 1, 2 or 3 equilibrium points. The number of equilibria changes only when graph $y = f(x)$  (where $f(x)$ is from equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$) touches the $Ox$ axis. So, if you solve $f(x, a, b) = 0, \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, a, b) = 0$, you can find the curves on parameter plane $(a, b)$ which are boundaries of regions with different number of equilibria.